# How to fix cmd error in VirtualBox Windows 95

Tags: cmd

I’m using Windows’s 95 on VirtualBox and during setup, I’m doing the following command

```
Copy R:\WIN95\*.* C:\WIN95
```

But when I read the command, it says the file is not found. Does anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Does R: exist? What is the output of the command `NET USE`? What is the output of the command `DIR R:\ `? This seems more suited to https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your floppy has xcopy.exe but no copy.exe.